# How to create listview navigation in shell tab bar using xamarin form cross platform?

Tags: shell, listview, xamarin, navigation

[image]Xamarin Forms Cross Platform.
1. I'm using Shell to create Tab Bar, one of the tab bar consist listview.
2. Each cell will navigate to the its details page.

My problem here:
Since I'm using Shell (new feature of xamarin 4.0), I've no idea how to make listview navigation page.

Appreciate those who know using shell navigation to enable my cells in listview able navigate to particular page.

```
<StackLayout  Orientation="Vertical">
        <Frame BackgroundColor="DarkOrange" HeightRequest="100" Margin="10,10,10,20" BorderColor="Black" HasShadow="True">

        </Frame>
        <ListView x:Name="ListView" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Red" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"

                  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding RightArrowIcon}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

async private void ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, 
SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var listview = e.SelectedItem as MeListView;
            var name = listview.Name.ToString();

            if (e.SelectedItem == null)
                return;

            ListView.SelectedItem = null; //clear the selected item when 
back to the listview.

            switch (name)
            {
                case "Payment Methods":                        
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new PaymentPage(listview));                        
                    break;
                case "Setting":
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new SettingPage(listview));
                    break;
                case "FAQ":
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new FaqPage(listview));
                    break;
                case "Terms & Conditions":
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new TermsPage(listview));
                    break;

                case "About us":
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new AboutPage(listview));
                    break;

                case "Contact us":
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new ContactPage(listview));
                    break;
            }                
        }                
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem here: Since I'm using Shell (new feature of xamarin 4.0), I've no idea how to make listview navigation page.

First add `ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"` to ListView in **Xaml**:

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListView" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Red" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            //...
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Then in `OnItemSelected` func, you can write your navigation function.In shell app, you also can use `Navigation.PushAsync` to navigat to next page. As follow:

```
void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var item = args.SelectedItem as Item;
    if (item == null)
        return;

    switch (args.SelectedItemIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
            Navigation.PushAsync(new PayMentPage());
            break;
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
            Navigation.PushAsync(new SettingPage());
            break;
        //...
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Default case");
            break;
    }
}
```

**In addition**, shell app offer new way to navigate ( `Shell.Current.GoToAsync` ).To do this , you should register page first by **Routes**. As follow:

**Register Page**:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("setting", typeof(SettingPage));
```

**Perform navigation**:

```
Shell.Current.GoToAsync("setting");
```

This is the easy way to use shell's navigation , there is other important points about Routes and Navigation .Here is the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation) for reference.

===================================Update====================================

If want to navigate to detail page ,and the Tab bar is not visible, you sholud manually do that in Detail Page.As follow:

```
Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false);
```

Comment: Hi sir, I understand your code and it is works. However, what I want is let say user select any row in the listview (e.g Setting), it will completely navigate to the Setting Page and hide the bottom tab bar, just left the back button on top so that user able to press it and back to the previous page (show the tab bar then).

Comment: @VVVoon Yeah , it should be .If your Flyout item (Setting Page) is not a Tab , then will navigate to new page view ,Tabbar will hide.This is the same as One Tab Page navigating to its detail Page. Have a look at this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/tabs).

Comment: but after I click any item on the listview , the tab bar doesn't hide!!

Comment: @VVVoon Okey , does the listview detail page belong to one of the Tab Page ? You can show ItemSelected method code in queestion, I will check it.

Comment: my complete selected method already uploaded to my question. my desired result is simple. I'm using Shell to create my Tab bar. Then, one of my Tab consist ListView with 6 items to choose. When user select any item, it will navigate to that item's details page (completely wrap the bottom tab bar), just left the back arrow button on top so user can click it go back to the ListView. I'm add content page for the Item's detail page.

Comment: @VVVoon Thanks for updating . Sorry for confusing shell application and tabbar .In shell app, you should manually to hide the tab bar when navigating to detail page.I have updated in answer.

Comment: I did used this ( Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false); ), it is works. But I feel a bit strange.

Comment: @VVVoon It is strange ,different from normal tab page . This is depend on the shell desigened. Here is the source code can be a reference. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/ShellRenderer.cs

Comment: I did used this ( Shell.SetTabBarIsVisible(this, false); ), it is works. But I feel a bit strange. 1st, when I click the "Payment Methods" item, then, I can see the system hide the bottom tab bar to the bottom, then the "details page" appear from my right to the left to occupied the full screen. Although all the motion is within a second, but I can see it clearly how the tabbar hide. Is there any other way?

Comment: @VVVoon This is  a animarion when hiding TabBar .It is a defaulf setting in Shell .If want to change this animation , maybe need custom shell renderer .

Comment: Hi sir, I found another problem of the code. when i select any cell in my listview, it's navigate to the detail page. but , the back button and title of the detail page is disappear ?

Comment: @VVVoon Okey, this not happens in my project . Maybe you can have a check with this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) . It has the Scenario you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built mechanism for this. But it is fairly simple to implement.

You can either use `ItemSelected` OR `ItemTapped` event of ListView as follows:

```
        <ListView x:Name="ListView" SeparatorVisibility="Default" SeparatorColor="Red" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}"/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"  FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" 
                                   HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                            <Image Source="{Binding RightArrowIcon}" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

In code behind:

```
async void OnListViewItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailsPage());
}
```

Comment: Hi sir, I understand your code and it is works. However, what I want is let say user select any row in the listview (e.g Setting), it will completely navigate to the Setting Page and hide the bottom tab bar, just left the back button on top so that user able to press it and back to the previous page (show the tab bar then).